# Jquery knob - the circle is not showing up in android device (micromax canvas)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-knob

I am using Jquery knob in one of my project to display a circular input control. Works fine in all browsers that supports HTML5 but when viewed in Micromax canvas A110 device the circle of the knob is not showing ? is this a problem with the browser or with device ?
Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0):

Atlast Myself found out the solution, just had to give data-angleOffset=1 with the input field to which the knob is binded.